# Is it possible to A/B test javascript-generated element variation using GA Experiments and GA Events?

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

I'm trying to do A/B testing using Google Experiments on a javascript-generated variation elements.

In simpler example, I'm trying to create a button using javascript that has different colors

The HTML is simple

```
<form id="foo"></form>
```

The button is generated like this

```
var color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % 2 == 1 ? 'red' : 'green';
$("#foo").append("<input type='submit' value='submit' style='background-color:" + color + "'/>")
$("#foo input[type='submit']").on('click', function(e){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cart', 'Submit']);
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/6Vvb5/).

In my Google Analytics, I use the event `'Cart'->'Submit'` as a conversion goal. I basically want to test which color has the highest conversion.

I can actually put the color in the event tracker, say `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cart', 'Submit', 'green']);` and do some filtering in the GA console.

I just knew about GA Experiments and I'm trying to learn about it. From what I understand in GA Experiments [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745152?hl=en&ref_topic=1745207), I have to create several pages to test. Is it possible to do this in one page but using different variation on javascript-generated element like above?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it on the same page by passing a parameter to the page, so http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html?version=2 and http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html

Set the colour of the button based on the parameter sent to the page.

Google Experiments work by redirecting anyone who lands on http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html to any URL of your choice ( which could then be http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html?version=2 ) should they be selected as part of the B testing group.

You should not be randomly generating the colour each time a user visits.  It needs to be constant for the A and B version.